# WKWebView shows gray background and pdf content gets invisible on viewcontroller switch

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, wkwebview

I am loading pdf file from main bundle or document directory in WKWebView. It loads perfectly initially but its shows gray background and pdf content gets invisible if I come back to same screen after tab switch in tabbar controller. Here is the code I am using to load

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    var pdfURLS: URL?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        pdfURLS = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "97_pdf", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("pdfURLS: \(String(describing: pdfURLS))")
    }

    @IBAction func loadAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if let pdfURL = pdfURLS  {
            self.webView.loadFileURL(pdfURL, allowingReadAccessTo: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
        }
    }
}
```

Someone has an idea about the issue?[image]

Image reference is attached. There is no such kind of problem if I use UIWebView which is deprecated, but I don't want to use deprecated library.

Comment: maybe your PDF url is getting released!!

Comment: @iOSer no it's not. There is no such kind of problem if I use UIWebView which is deprecated, but I don't want to use deprecated library.

Comment: Agreed there no point going for a deprecated library. Another reason could be maybe you are adding another instance of WKWebView, while coming back to the this tab.  In all honesty its hard to nail down why without code.

Comment: Added code reference. There are no two instances.

Comment: Hi, can you try to add these lines : `let request = URLRequest(url: pdfURL)
self.webView.load(request)` after `self.webView.loadFileURL` ?

Comment: @AliAbbas : Not working. I had also tried using data loading. Again, no luck. I found some references for allowingReadAccessTo to some previous or root path. which is also not working. Very strange behaviour. Still not working.

Comment: I create a sample project and I reproduce the issue. Checking that.

Comment: I created a sample project too shows up just fine for me. Even after changing the view controllers. Could be simulator related issue at your end. There are two suggestions I would like to make. 1) Ensure you are loading on the main thread. 2) Delete the derived data and try again. 3) Check on device as well

Comment: @iOSer Please check on device. I am using iPad/iOS12

Comment: I tried on an iPhone XR simulator, I have the issue. Also, on a real device, It's not actually working.

Comment: This is the project sample: https://github.com/aliabbas90/wkwebviewPDF

Comment: @AliAbbas Thanks, I am not sure if it is issue related to library

Comment: I have done some tweaks for temporary fixes but it is not ideal fix. I am setting a flag = true in viewWillAppear for first load and next time checking if it is true and webView.reload()

We can also save contentOffset of scrollView of webView and can set it in some delay (as reload takes some time) so that user can redirect to exact offset where it was last time. But it is not ideal fix

Comment: This must be a bug for iOS 12. I am getting the grey screen too when coming back to the view (after it initially loads fine). It's happening in every iOS 12 simulator I tried as well as my iOS 12 device. I never had this problem before iOS 12. I checked to see if a normal website works (apple.com) and it does. It seems to only not be working for PDF...

Comment: Have you got any better solution for this issue ? @RajSharma

Comment: @MayankPatel Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution till now.

Comment: Has anyone got the solution? @RajSharma

Comment: @Anurag I didn't find any solution till now. Did some tweak to handle issue mentioned in previous comments

Comment: Checked on iOS 13.2.2 Still issue is not fixed

Comment: @RajSharma Any Luck on this issue?  I shocked this is still going on in iOS 13.

Comment: @user1184205 I have checked a few days before. Still not resolved.

Answer (score 13):

We ran into this problem in Firefox for iOS as well:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1516524

I've also referenced this SO post in a WebKit bug:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193281

For the time being, we found a workaround:

```
let previousZoomScale = webView.scrollView.zoomScale
let previousContentOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset

if let currentItem = webView.backForwardList.currentItem {
    webView.go(to: currentItem)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
    webView.scrollView.setZoomScale(previousZoomScale, animated: false)
    webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(previousContentOffset, animated: false)
}
```

Basically, we revisit the URL from the back/forward history list which redraws the PDF then we restore the scrollview position/zoom. Its not great, but it works.

Comment: the pdf goes back to first page if user had zoomed in on the content despite setting the value for contentOffset.. Seems like the setting the zoomScale is resetting the contentOffset for some reason even though zoomScale was set before contentOffset :(

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to apply a workaround! I found that the restore of zoom and contentOffset should be applied after the navigation finished (webView:didFinishNavigation), otherwise too many times their values weren't properly restored. Even inside 'webView:didFinishNavigation' I had to use DispatchQueue.main with a 50/100 milliseconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reloading pdf data in *viewWillAppear*.
So far it works.
Data are first loaded from storage/web.

```
var data: Data?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  if let data = data {
    webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
  }
}
```